# how to get user id page views google anaytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to view user id and page views in one report as the below:
[client id with page views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOt2y.png)

I have created custiome user id and in the report I can't get pages users viewed. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible by deafult the only way you can archive this is creating a Custom Dimention and storing the UserID there.

Hope it helps!

Comment: @Mustafa Why? Could you be more precise? I've archive this in the past. Send the UserID duplicated on each hit ones on the uid and again on the cdX

Comment: Hi Marco, Please check te below steps:
On the left menu of Google Analytics I click on Audience, then User Explorer
I see then a list of User Id, Sessions etc.
I click on a user ID let us say: 324324
Then I see the traffic user made in a period of time, I have to click on each time under each date to view traffic, this is fine, but not very usefull, I need a list of users and the pages they accessed. Hope this is more clear